# How to convert a Date got at runtime from user in String format into Date format to feed it in the database

Tags: java, datetime, jdbc

```
public Date getTransactionDate()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the transaction Date");
        String date = sc.next();
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
       String s1 = df.format(date);
       Date d1 = null;
       try
       {
           d1 = (Date) df.parse(s1);
       } catch (java.text.ParseException e)
       {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
          return d1;
   }

Date d2 = new PreparedStmnt().getTransactionDate();

public static void addTransaction(Connection connection, PreparedStatement preparedStatement , long transac_Id , Date transac_date) 
    throws SQLException
{
    String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS VALUES (?,?)";
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
    preparedStatement.setLong(1, transac_Id);
    preparedStatement.setDate(2, transac_date);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Its a Simple Transaction entry where i want the user to provide date at runtime and then store that in the database.But while doing so, I'm getting a bug saying:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot              format given Object as a Date 
        at java.text.DateFormat.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)
        at bluePrint.PreparedStmnt.getTransactionDate(PreparedStmnt.java:76)
        at bluePrint.PreparedStmnt.main(PreparedStmnt.java:30)

Well this is my first project m working on. So, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

you should use sc.nextLine() Instead sc.next() because its not consider space 
you can try like

```
System.out.println("Enter the transaction Date");
        String string = "January 2, 2010";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        string = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(string);
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(string);

            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

this worked for me. entered date format January 2, 2010